# How to sort columns of several data frames in a list?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, time, timestamp

I have a list in R, with several data frames having timestamp as a column. I want to sort this column in all of them. How can I do it?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1):

in base R

```
L <- list(data.frame(v1 = 3:1, v2 = 1:3), 
          data.frame(v1 = 6:4, v2 = 4:6))
# [[1]]
#   v1 v2
# 1  3  1
# 2  2  2
# 3  1  3
# 
# [[2]]
#   v1 v2
# 1  6  4
# 2  5  5
# 3  4  6

lapply(L, function(x) x[order(x$v1), ])
# [[1]]
#   v1 v2
# 3  1  3
# 2  2  2
# 1  3  1
# 
# [[2]]
#   v1 v2
# 3  4  6
# 2  5  5
# 1  6  4
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `tidyverse` - loop over the `list` with `map` (from `purrr`) and `arrange` the rows based on the 'timestamp' column

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
lst2 <- map(lst1, ~ .x %>%
                    arrange(timestamp))
```